# R symbol lookup error

Tags: r

Whenever I try to start R from the terminal, I get this error

```
/usr/lib64/R/bin/exec/R: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libR.so: 
undefined symbol: tre_regcompb
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling R. I have also downloaded the R rpm from the CRAN site and installed it locally but the problem persists.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Do you have Anaconda installed? If so, kill it with fire.

Comment: @DavidArenburg You don't like Anaconda?

Comment: It's the source of all evil when it comes unexpected bugs/errors/etc.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Indeed I do have anaconda. But I also have it in like four other machines which are quite okay when it comes to R